# Printing out subprocess when regex captures

Tags: python, regex, subprocess

I am running a bash command in python with:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
proc.wait()
```

This cmd prints an output. However I dont want it to print unless it is captured by some regex. Not sure how to do this as this is my first time using `subprocess`

Comment: You could also simply pipe the output to grep

Answer (score 2):

You could do also pipe the output directly to grep etc..:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

p = Popen(["ps"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "chrome"],stdin=p.stdout, stdout=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
p.stdout.close()

out,err = p2.communicate()
print(out)

 421 ?        00:00:03 chrome
 767 ?        00:00:02 chrome
 843 ?        00:00:04 chrome
 2788 ?        00:52:16 chrome
 2819 ?        00:00:00 chrome-sandbox
 2820 ?        00:00:00 chrome
 2827 ?        00:00:00 chrome-sandbox
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
```

To check any output/error you can apply your regex on `(out,err)`, and print whatever you want.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the simple case you should be able to use `subprocess.check_output` to get the result of a call. In Python3 this returns a `bytes` object. In Python2 it's a `str` as usual.

```
# Python3
result_in_bytes = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
result = result_in_bytes.decode() # -> string

# Python2
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

Then you should be able to run your regex on that string.

Answer (score 1):

To emulate the shell pipeline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

output = Popen("cmd | grep 'pattern'", shell=True,
               stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

without the shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

grep = Popen(['grep', 'pattern'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
cmd_process = Popen(['cmd'], stdout=grep.stdin)
output = grep.communicate()[0]
cmd_process.wait()
```

Or you could filter `cmd`'s output in pure Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

matched_lines = []
cmd_process = Popen(['cmd'], stdout=PIPE)
with cmd_process.stdout:
    for line in iter(cmd_process.stdout.readline, b''):
        if b'pattern' in line: # or re.match(br'pattern', line)
            matched_lines.append(line)
cmd_process.wait()
```