# `ps -ef` shows running process twice if started with `subprocess.Popen`

Tags: python, linux, python-3.4, ps

I use the following snippet in a larger Python program to spawn a process in background:

```
import subprocess

command = "/media/sf_SharedDir/FOOBAR"
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

After that I wanted to check whether the process was running when my Python program returned.
Output of `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep FOOBAR`:

```
ap    3396   937  0 16:08 pts/16   00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /media/sf_SharedDir/FOOBAR
ap    3397  3396  0 16:08 pts/16   00:00:00 /bin/sh /media/sf_SharedDir/FOOBAR
```

I was surprised to see two lines of and they have differend PIDs so are those two processes running? Is there something wrong with my `Popen` call?

`FOOBAR` Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while : 
do
        echo "still alive"
        sleep 1
done
```

**EDIT:** Starting the script in a terminal `ps` displayes only one process.

Started via `./FOOBAR`

```
ap@VBU:/media/sf_SharedDir$ ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep FOOBAR
ap    4115  3463  0 16:34 pts/5    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./FOOBAR
```

**EDIT:** `shell=True` is causing this issue (if it is one). But how would I fix that if I required `shell` to be True to run bash commands?

Comment: I see no output and only one process, I did chmod +x the file and run without shell=True

Comment: First time I though I had one process still running and forgot about that but after killing them all and rerunning the python script I saw two processes again.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you are right. `shell=True` is causing this. But how would I fix this if I require it to be `True`?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(command)`, just make the script executable and `./`, why would you need shell=True?

Comment: Because in my programm I need to run shell commands with options and arguments. It is not only a single file I try to run. And in this case - if I understood correctly - I need the `shell=True` flag. For example I also run `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep ...` through `Popen`.

Comment: you can pipe with Popen, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29085292/2141635 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710529/error-is-being-raised-when-executing-a-sub-process-using/31710577#31710577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, what you see is perfectly normal. There is no "fix".

Each of your processes has a distinct function. The top-level process is running the python interpreter.

The second process, `/bin/sh -c /media/sf_SharedDir/FOOBAR'` is the shell that interprets the cmd line (because you want `|` or `*` or `$HOME` to be interpreted, you specified `shell=True`).

The third process, `/bin/sh /media/sf_SharedDir/FOOBAR` is the FOOBAR cmd. The `/bin/sh` comes from the `#!` line inside your FOOBAR program. If it were a C program, you'd just see `/media/sf_SharedDir/FOOBAR` here. If it were a python program, you'd see `/usr/bin/python/media/sf_SharedDir/FOOBAR`.

If you are really bothered by the second process, you could modify your python program like so:

```
command = "exec /media/sf_SharedDir/FOOBAR"
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```